# Activation Function for Trainable Variable in a Custom Layer Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, layer

I'm trying to create a custom layer to merge two different branches of my network:

**output = alpha*A+beta*B**

where A and B are the output vectors of each branch and alpha and beta are trainable vector parameters.

Following [Keras Guide](https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/) I write this custom layer:

```
class MergeTwo(keras.layers.Layer):

def __init__(self, nout, **kwargs):
    super(MergeTwo, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    alpha = tf.zeros_initializer()
    beta = tf.zeros_initializer()

    self.alpha = tf.Variable(initial_value=alpha(shape=(nout,)),dtype='float32',trainable=True)

    self.beta = tf.Variable(initial_value=beta(shape=(nout,)),dtype='float32',trainable=True)

def call(self, inputs):
    A, B = inputs
    result = keras.layers.add([self.alpha*A ,self.beta*B])
    return result
```

Is it correct?

I'd like to set the activation function *(tanh)* for alpha and beta. What should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Add layer is already implemented.  You should use it: https://keras.io/api/layers/merging_layers/add/.

Comment: Thank you, but this is  A+B without any parameters. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are right.  To add activation, simply apply keras.activations.tanh in the call method.

Comment: I add result = keras.activations.tanh(result) as you suggested, thank you!